# OpenGL: Window Coordinates to Actual Pixel Coordinates

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

The question I have is quite fundamental but for some strange reason I could not find a straight answer to this anywhere on the web:

How can I interpret OpenGL Window Coordinates?

I know how the NDC --> Window Coordinates transformation works but what I don't see is a definition of how OpenGL's "Window Coordinates" relate to actual pixel coordinates (where typically pixel centers are at whole numbers). It's basically a +/- 0.5 pixel question.

From the OpenGL 4.5 spec (13.6.1 -- Controlling the Viewport):
"... x and y give the location of the viewport's lower left corner ..."

So does "lower left corner" mean
a) the lower left corner **of the lowest-leftmost pixel** or
b) just the pixel coordinate of the lowest leftmost pixel?

If it's a) then I guess to go from Window Coordinates to Pixel coordinates one would have to subtract 0.5 from the WC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL coordinates are the lower-left of the pixel. You'll need to add half to get the pixel center.

https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/fragment_coord_conventions.txt

Comment: Thanks for this resource. I wish Khronos would put this information in a more prominent location than an obscure extension man page...

Comment: For OpenGL ES 3.1 (latest spec for ES) the fact that it is lower left is covered in section 12.5.1 "Controlling the Viewport". The fact that you need half offset is a little harder to find, but search for "pixel center" in the spec and you'll find something embedded in the multisampling section ;)